# Ubuntu can't connect to the internet, restart required

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet

Today for the 4th time this month, 
Ubuntu suddenly disables my Ethernet, 
I'm connected through Alcatel Speed Touch (yeah I know it's an oldie). 
I tried to log out and log back in, tried ifconfig and it didn't recognized 
any Ethernet modem connected. 
Only after a reset did it work... like every time before. 
Any ideas?

**UPDATE** 
Tried to enter 
/etc/init.d/gdm restart  
and then after the gui restarted 
sudo dhclient eth0

That worekd, but I still want to know what's wrong 
and why does it stop working all the time

**UPDATE 2** 
the dhclient eth0 thing doesn't work anymore. 
Any ideas?

Comment: output of dmesg?

Comment: next time it happens I promise, but I can't predict that, any guesses ?

Comment: guess what, happened again, dmesg https://gist.github.com/724a661f86d6305c4538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known bug with r8169 ethernet cards. For reference, it is bug #566389 on the Redhat bug tracker or #605045 on the Network-Manager Ubuntu bug tracker.

A current workaround is to place this in /etc/pm/sleep.d/85-network-r8169-module [1]

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
  hibernate | suspend)
    echo "Removing r8169."
    modprobe -r r8169
    ;;
thaw | resume)
    echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
    modprobe r8169
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

However, it will make resuming a bit slower.

[1] https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=566389#c6

Comment: If it's NetworkManager bug, why not just switch to Wicd?

Comment: Ok so I'll just make a command that I'll run if it won't connect, what's the exact command I should run to make it work? modprobe -r r8169 and then modprobe r8169 ?